# How to trick Make into running commands in subfolders dynamically

Tags: makefile

I am trying to get Make to run commands from subfolders that it is unaware of in the root makefile.

I hae the following makefile at the project root:

```
ARGS=$(filter-out $@, $(MAKECMDGOALS))

.PHONY: build
build:
    @$(MAKE) -C ${ARGS} build

%:
    @$(MAKE) -C ${ARGS}
```

I have the following at `./folder`

```
build:
    @echo "Mushrooms!"
.PHONY: build

badgers:
    @echo "Badgers!"
.PHONY: badger
```

So, when I run `make build folder` I get the echo "Mushrooms!" as expected. When I run `make folder badgers` though, I get the same echo.

I assumed that it was running correctly the first run, but it seems to be ignoring any arguments (i.e. the sub-command I want to run) and just running the first entry in `./folder/makefile`.

Does anyone know how I can trick make into calling the correct command from the subfolder?

Comment: Never turn off command echoing (via prepending an `@`) until you are confident that the makefile is working as intended.  And maybe not even then.  Suppressing command echo hides information that can be crucial for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enabled command echoing in your top-level makefile, you would see that in the `make folder badgers` case, the recursive `make` command that is executed is `make -C folder`, not `make -C folder badgers`.  Why? Because when `${ARGS}` is expanded in the context of the match-anything rule, the target is `badgers`, and you explicitly filter the target out of the expansion!

You might also have been clued in by the fact that both your `make` commands print a message about `folder` being up to date.  This tells you that it is choosing not executing a recipe for building `folder`.  In the case of `make build folder`, then, the top-level make is running only the recipe for target `build`, which re-introduces 'build' into the goal list of the sub-make.  In the case of `make folder badgers`, it executes only the recipe for `badgers`, which does not reintroduce that target into the submake, so the submake builds the default target.

I would suggest something less magic: rely on defining a macro on the command line.  The makefile would look like this:

```
.PHONY: build

# Just for the purpose of having a default target
build:
    make -C $(subdir) "$@"

%:
    make -C $(subdir) "$@"
```

You would then run `make` like so:

```
make subdir=folder
make subdir=folder build
make subdir=folder badgers
```

That still leaves a few holes, such as what happens if the user does not specify a value for `subdirs`, but its at minimum a firmer foundation on which to build.